# Oil change on isuzu box truck

Tags: oil-change, truck, isuzu

My husband changed the oil on his isuzu box truck and he says he did eveything exactly as he was suppose to but this morning he got up and drove it and it went into regin and then he seen alot of smoke and it shut off on the highway he said there was alot of oil on the highway can his truck be messed up??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line answer of "can it be messed up" is **absolutely**. Whether the work your husband did is at fault for the loss of oil would still need to be figured out, however, there's still a serious issue whatever the cause.

What could have caused the loss of oil? The easiest thing to point a finger at would be something like the oil filter failing, or possibly having the old oil filter gasket (o-ring) not coming off with the old filter. If there are two o-rings on the oil filter boss, it will lose integrity and fail, blowing oil all over the place and causing a situation like what you've described.

It could also be something worse, like the engine itself has just decided this would be a good time to throw a rod out the side of the block. A scenario like this would most likely be completely unrelated to the oil change, but is still a possibility ... an extreme possibility and highly unlikely, but still a possibility.

The van will need to be taken somewhere a diagnosis can be performed. There's just about no way for us to be able to tell you what's going on. The bottom line is, there's something messed up. Whether it's a huge problem or a small one is yet to be seen.

Comment: Funny... the two oil filter ring thing.  Worked on someones Mustang recently.  They changed oil & filter and didn't realize the old seal got stuck on the engine when they added a new filter with seal,  Two seals worked for a bit, then failed dramatically, with lots of oil and smoke everywhere . Good call.

Comment: Both my Town and Countries had this problem. About every 4 times I change the oil, the seal stays on the engine. I never start the car after an oil change until I have the old seal in sight.